# Init not being called PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an init function in my ManagedBean that is view scoped. But I can't seem to get it to run when the page loads.
   Its a private field in this Class

```
 .............
      package mike.food;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ManagedBean(name = "nutrition")
@ViewScoped
public class NutritionixResponse implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1016196967087965738L;
    private String total_hits;
    private String max_score;
    private ArrayList<Hits> hits;
    private ArrayList<Hits> droppedhits;
    public NutritionixResponse() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {


    }

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {

            this.droppedhits = new ArrayList<Hits>();
        }
    public String getTotal_hits() {
        return total_hits;
    }
    public void setTotal_hits(String total_hits) {
        this.total_hits = total_hits;
    }
    public String getMax_score() {
        return max_score;
    }
    public void setMax_score(String max_score) {
        this.max_score = max_score;
    }
    public ArrayList<Hits> getHits() {
        return hits;
    }
    public void setHits(ArrayList<Hits> hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
    }


    public ArrayList<Hits> getDroppedhits() {
        return droppedhits;
    }


    public void setDroppedhits(ArrayList<Hits> droppedhits) {
        this.droppedhits = droppedhits;
    }





}
```

The main class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Manaents Serializable {
gedBean(name = "FoodClient")
@ViewScoped
public class FoodClient implem
    /**
     * Need to test something
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3874520453001209544L;
    private NutritionixResponse nurition;
```

And the page

```
<p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
                    <p:dataTable id="droppedfoodtable" var="food"
                        value="#{FoodClient.nurition.droppedhits}"
```

Comment: What do you mean, "*But I can seem to get it to run when the page loads*"? It is an affirmative sentence. It means that the said method is invoked on page load - you seem to have managed to get it to be invoked. Is there any question then onwards?

Comment: Sorry, Typo can -> can't

Comment: How are you referencing the bean in the view?

Comment: Here `value="#{FoodClient.nurition.droppedhits}"`, what is `FoodClient`? It does not match the managed bean name over here `@ManagedBean(name = "nutrition")`.

Comment: I added more info. Its a hierarchical situation that is needed for the JSon response to be populated. Everything is working but instead of putting this in a Constructor, I want to use init(). Bu not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is the scope annotation `@ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` hereby **not** from `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`?

Comment: Its from bean.ViewScoped . this gives me nothing: import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but where is the first bean injected in the second?